# Mock document.referrer Angular Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to provide a different value for

```
document.referrer
```

for my unit tests. How can I mock it and provide a customized value?

Answer (score 5):

Inspecting `document.referrer`, we find that it is a getter:
[image]

With Jasmine 2.6, you can create a spy to change the return value of any getter functions.

```
spyOnProperty(document, 'referrer', 'get').and.returnValue('http://foobar.com');
expect(document.referrer).toBe('http://foobar.com');
```

You can read more in the latest [API documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.6/global.html#spyOnProperty).